# Is there a cleaner and more repeatable way to code this onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding many, many lines of these circles that are fillable based on a click function.  Imagine a form where you can fill a certain number of these to denote levels of an attribute (these are for and RPG character sheet).  So there are hundreds of lines of these between all the attributes and characters.  Edit: The client has given me two images to use for this, an empty circle and a filled circle.
Here's how I've coded two lines of circles:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:130.47px;top:155.30px" class="cls_005"><span class="cls_005">Intelligence</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:213.52px;top:144.41px" class="cls_006"><span class="cls_006"><p>
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange2" onclick="changeImageTwo()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange3" onclick="changeImageThree()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange4" onclick="changeImageFour()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange5" onclick="changeImageFive()"  />
</p>

<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
        function changeImageTwo() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
        function changeImageThree() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
            function changeImageFour() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
            function changeImageFive() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
</script></span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:600.48px;top:155.30px" class="cls_005"><span class="cls_005">Strength</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:650.53px;top:157.41px" class="cls_006"><span class="cls_006"><p>
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange6" onclick="changeImageSix()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange7" onclick="changeImageSeven()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange8" onclick="changeImageEight()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange9" onclick="changeImageNine()"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" id="imgClickAndChange10" onclick="changeImageTen()"  />
</p>

<script language="javascript">
    function changeImageSix() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
        function changeImageSeven() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
        function changeImageEight() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
            function changeImageNine() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
            function changeImageTen() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange10").src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange10").src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange10").src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
        }
    }
</script></span></div>
```

So, as you can see, lots of lines of code.  Would love a way to simplify this.  Thank your for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. You can use one handler for the document and use a generic handler ([event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)). In this case something like the given snippet. In the snippet a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is used to recognize an image

```js
document.addEventListener("click", changeImage);

function changeImage(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.dataset.togglesrc) {
    const swap = {"8apyMiH.png": "QJVkq9A.png", "QJVkq9A.png": "8apyMiH.png"};
    const imgRoot = origin.src.substr(0, origin.src.lastIndexOf("/"));
    const currentImg = origin.src.split("/").slice(-1);
    origin.src = `${imgRoot}/${swap[currentImg]}`;
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin: 2rem;}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" data-togglesrc="1"
      style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange6" />
  <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" data-togglesrc="1"
      style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange7" />
  <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" data-togglesrc="1"
      style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange8" />
  <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" data-togglesrc="1"
      style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange9"  />
  <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" data-togglesrc="1"
      style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange10" />
```

Alternatively you can create a more generic factory function that returns a handler and receives the image file names as parameter:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", swapper("JouzaLc.png", "rgqRxiB.png"));

function swapper(...images) {
  const swap = {
    [images[0]]: images[1],
    [images[1]]: images[0],
  };
  // return a listener function
  // the function uses the 'closed over' [swap] variable
  return evt => {
    const origin = evt.target;
    if (origin.dataset.imageId) {
      const imgRoot = origin.src.substr(0, origin.src.lastIndexOf("/"));
      const currentImg = origin.src.split("/").slice(-1).pop();
      origin.src = `${imgRoot}/${swap[currentImg]}`;
      console.clear();
      console.log(`You clicked image ${origin.dataset.imageId}, its src is now ${
        swap[currentImg]}`);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JouzaLc.png" data-image-id="11" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JouzaLc.png" data-image-id="2" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JouzaLc.png" data-image-id="23" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JouzaLc.png" data-image-id="46" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JouzaLc.png" data-image-id="15" />
</p>
```

Yet another idea may be to also use `data-attibutes` for the images to swap. That one can be [found in a JsBin](https://jsbin.com/kubonag/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Code works here running the snippet.  For some reason it's not working when I run it locally.  Can this work within an html file with the JS enclosed with script tags, and the rest in the body section?

Comment: Yes, it should work. [See this demo](https://jsbin.com/guvilid/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to look into using function parameters better.
All your functions are doing the same thing, with different *parameters* - in your case, the parameters are an element's ID and two image URLs.

The point of a function is not just to encapsulate some code (i.e., separate a chunk of code into a block, as you're doing) - but to take some input (parameters), manipulate it, and return some output.

In your case, you might consider a function that looks like this:

```js
const changeImageSrc = function(imageID, oldURL, newURL){
  const image = document.getElementById(imageID)
  if(image.src === oldURL){
    image.src = newURL
  }
}
```

Now you can call this function as many times as you like, each time passing it the relevant parameters:

```js
changeImageSrc("imgClickAndChange10", "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png", "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png")
changeImageSrc("imgClickAndChange9", ...)
```

There's other changes you can make too, like storing all your URLs/IDs in an array, or even getting them from the got go using `document.getElementsByClassName` if you're setting your HTML up a certain way, then looping to make your life easier - but that's a whole other story.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same functionality for all the images, you only need one function, you can pass as parameter the DOM HTML element with `this`, something like:

```
<img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
```

And your adapted function will look something like this:

```js
function changeImage(element) {
      const src = element.src
      src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" ? element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png" : element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
  }
```

Your code will look something like:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function changeImage(element) {
      const src = element.src
      src == "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" ? element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/8apyMiH.png" : element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png";
  }
</script>

<div style="position:absolute;left:130.47px;top:155.30px" class="cls_005"><span class="cls_005">Intelligence</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:213.52px;top:144.41px" class="cls_006"><span class="cls_006"><p>
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
</p>
</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:600.48px;top:155.30px" class="cls_005"><span class="cls_005">Strength</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:650.53px;top:157.41px" class="cls_006"><span class="cls_006"><p>
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.imgur.com/QJVkq9A.png" 
            style="height: 10px; width: 10px" onclick="changeImage(this)"  />
</p>
</span></div>
```

Comment: It is the most efficient way I could think of so as not to make the page load slow

Comment: There are many ways to assign event handlers, but inline ones aren't the best for performance and maintainability